# Editing <body> tag in joomla

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, joomla, joomla3.0, scrollspy

I'm trying to implement [scrollspy](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#scrollspy) in joomla using bootstrap and I need to include some classes and other tags in  and  of page.

How can I  find the code containing  and  of my joomla page?

Answer (score 2):

You can edit your template files in: `/templates/your-template-name/index.php`

Here you can find what you need.

You should use a file manager or ftp.